# include_path working fine with php, but not working in .htaccess... what gives?

Tags: set-include-path

I just moved some programs from 1 server to another. They were working on the old server... (I know that's loaded, but from what I see it shouldn't make a difference). I've looked at the "similar titles" questions, but cannot find anything like what is happening here. I would like to use the .htaccess file to set this path like I've done in the past. So far I have in PHP:

```
set_include_path('includes/');
echo get_include_path();
```

...in my htaccess I have tried:

```
php_value include_path includes/
```

..and:

```
php_value include_path /srv/www/htdocs/teams/includes/
```

However, cannot get it to work with the .htaccess file. It works with the .php file, but i'd like it to work with the .htaccess file for ease.

Any thoughts or ideas?!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Apache or mod_php is not set up correctly:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php

Also, make sure that your current working directory `"."` is in the include path.